# Why does google console report unexpected pixel size for <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following the code to Head First's Javascript book and I noticed something unsettling in my google console. If I drill down in the console in the elements section, when I highlight a  tag the browser tells me it is 96 and not 94 pixels! Its maddening and I cannot figure out why :(

BTW, the resources and code can be downloaded at: [code download](http://wickedlysmart.com/hfjs/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Battleship</title>
    <style>
        body 
        {
            background-color: black;
        }

        div#board 
        {
            position: relative;
            width: 1024px;
            height: 863px;
            margin: auto;
            background: url("board.jpg") no-repeat;
        }
        div#messageArea
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            color: rgb(83, 175, 19);
        }
        table
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 173px;
            top: 98px;
            border-spacing: 0px;
        }
        td
        {
            width: 94px;
            height: 94px;
        }
        form
        {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: rgb(83, 175, 19);
        }
        form input
        {
            background-color: rgb(152, 207, 113);
            border-color: rgb(83, 175, 19);
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .hit
        {
            background: url("ship.png") no-repeat center center;
        }
        .miss
        {
            background: url("miss.png") no-repeat center center;
        }


    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="board">
            <div id="messageArea"></div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="00"></td> <td id="01"></td> <td id="02"></td> <td id="03"></td>
                    <td id="04"></td> <td id="05"></td> <td id="06"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="10"></td> <td id="11"></td> <td id="12"></td> <td id="13"></td>
                    <td id="14"></td> <td id="15"></td> <td id="16"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="20"></td> <td id="21"></td> <td id="22"></td> <td id="23"></td>
                    <td id="24"></td> <td id="25"></td> <td id="26"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="30"></td> <td id="31"></td> <td id="32"></td> <td id="33"></td>
                    <td id="34"></td> <td id="35"></td> <td id="36"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="40"></td> <td id="41"></td> <td id="42"></td> <td id="43"></td>
                    <td id="44"></td> <td id="45"></td> <td id="46"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="50"></td> <td id="51"></td> <td id="52"></td> <td id="53"></td>
                    <td id="54"></td> <td id="55"></td> <td id="56"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="60"></td> <td id="61"></td> <td id="62"></td> <td id="63"></td>
                    <td id="64"></td> <td id="65"></td> <td id="66"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="guessInput" placeholder="A0">
                <input type="button" id="fireButton" value="Fire!">
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="battleship.js"></script>
    </body>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
td {
    width  : 94px;
    height : 94px;
}
```

to this:

```
td {
    width   : 94px;
    height  : 94px;
    padding : 0;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/seancannon/daLbQ/

Comment: Is 2px padding a default?

Comment: Probably 1px, on either side.